# What is the difference between software and a software component?

Tags: architecture, software-design

This may be a dumb question, but I really get confuse of how software are created. I am adware that application are software, but I also heard that component software are software to build application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"component software" isn't really a thing.  "Software Components" are small software applications that are designed to plug into a larger application framework in order to be useful.  The idea is much like a PC's components, the video card is a component of hardware, but it isn't useful unless it is plugged into a larger application (the computer).

An example of a software component would be a browser plugin.  It doesn't do anything on its own, it has to be plugged into the larger application to be valuable.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification